# How do i run my jupyter notebook as a service from a virtual environment

Tags: ubuntu, service, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, systemd

I am trying to run jupyter-notebook on my ubuntu 18.04 server as a service from a virtualenv.

I have created a run_jupyter.service inside /etc/systemd/system

`/home/azure/notebook/venv/bin/python3 /home/azure/notebook/venv/bin/jupyter-notebook`

above code while running from terminal runs jupyter notebook from my virtualenv, but same line when written in service running jupyter form default environment.

```
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
User=azure
WorkingDirectory=/home/azure/notebook/venv/bin/jupyter notebook 

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

any help in order to run my **notebook as a service from virtualenv** will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify which command have to be started with **ExecStart**

```
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
User=azure
WorkingDirectory=/home/azure/notebook
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/azure/notebook/venv/bin/jupyter notebook

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Moreover, user specific services can be located in **${HOME}/.config/systemd/user/** and started as:

```
$ systemctl --user jupyter.service
```